# setStyle with a problem

Tags: openlayers

I need to set up a style in time of creating a feature in OpenLayers. But besides my style var works, I know this because I've tested setting the style in the layer declaration, when I use the setStyle function, it does not works.

Here is my styles var:

```
 var styles = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
        })
    })
];

var styles15 = function () {
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(80, 233, 179,1)'
        })
    })];
};

var styles610 = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'yellow',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(213, 236, 70, 1)'
        })
    })
];

var styles1115 = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'orange',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(246, 149, 56, 1)'
        })
    })
];

var styles15mais = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'purple',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 119, 1)'
        })
    })
];
```

and this is where I try to set up the style and does not works:

```
    function assignFeaturesToPolygon() {
    var lot = [];
    lotes.forEach(function (value, index) {
        var new_feature = criarFeature(value);
        new_feature.setStyle(styles1115);
        lot.push(new_feature);
    });
    return lot;
};
```

But if I set up the style here:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    name: 'bairros', 
    style: styles
});
```

It works, but use this solution will not work for me, because I need to build a heat map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
function assignFeaturesToPolygon() {
    lotes.forEach(function (value, index) {
        var new_feature = criarFeature(value);
        var teste = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

        if (teste == 1) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles15);
        } else if (teste == 2) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles610);
        } else if (teste == 3) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles1115);
        } else if (teste == 4) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles15mais);
        }
        vectorSource.addFeature(new_feature);            
    });
};
```